# Is “[...]planning to give all my endeavor[...]” grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

I have this sentence:

> I am planning to give all my endeavor to help my homeland and my citizens as well.

I used to listen to English, not write it. So, from the sense of listening, I think it is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather say "I am planning to make every endeavor to help my homeland, and my citizens as well." since *endeavor* means "an attempt to do something." *Endeavor* is especially the American English spelling; British English would probably use *endeavour*.

As for "and my citizens as well," it is probably not necessary, as *homeland* should be understood to include the inhabitants. It is probably better to use *my compatriots*, which means all the people who were born, or are the citizens of, the same country as you were born or are citizen of.

Comment: kiamlaluno, there is no probably about it. In the UK, the spelling is *endeavour* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/endeavour_1?q=endeavour